# Can't ssh after configuring sshd_config

Tags: ssh, ipv6, openvz, dedicated-server, putty

I have configured my sshd configuration files to listen to ipv6 addresses, but forgot to uncomment ipv4 local addresses. Here is a snippet from my configuration file:

```
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0(forgot to uncomment this)
ListenAddress ::
```

After a server reboot I tried to login via putty but couldn't. Now I can't access my server.

Can I access through rescue mode? Is it possible to regain access without reinstalling the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- boot into rescue mode
- mount root filesystem (if not already mounted)
- restore old ssh config or fix your mistakes (in your rootfs, not the one from rescue system e.g `/some/mount/point/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)
- reboot into regular mode
- profit ;)

Comment: hello can you please tell me how to mount root files @Henrik

Comment: with `mount` - the parameters hardly depend on your disk layout (Raid, LVM, number of partition)...A good starting point is to have a look into `lsblk` --- but to be honest, mounting a file system is very basic Linux knowledge - maybe you want to get some professional help with your server or dig really fast into this topic because otherwise you may end as a spamserver or botnet-member...